# perl-global enviornment variables

Tags: perl, cmd

I am using set command in cmd to assign global variables

```
set TEMPDATA = C:\temp_data
```

In the same cmd session I am calling a Perl script

```
my $temp_path =  $ENV{'TEMPDATA'}."\\temp.c";
```

But it gives this error:

```
use of uninitialised value $ENV{'TEMPDATA'}.
```

when I use setx then it works.

But I need to have a temporary variable which should be deleted as soon as session is closed and for that I need to use set only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not include blank spaces in variable declaration. Use like this:

```
set TEMPDATA=C:\temp_data
```